# Spring Cloud Stream -Exactly once semantics | Messages get replayed even after exactly once

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am looking to enable exactly once semantics in my spring-cloud-stream application
I have noticed that when I start my server back after a weekend or if the server starts after any of the broker is down, all messages which were even complete get replayed, even though I have exactly once enabled.

The properties I am using
REST LAYER MODULE - where streamBridge.send("topic-name") resides

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.enable.idempotence=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings-inpProcess-out-0.destination=<destination>
```

The kafka module ( where my consumer resides)

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings-inpProcess-in-0.destination=<destination>
spring.cloud.stream.bindings-inpProcess1-in-0.destination=<destination>
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.inpProcess-in-0.consumer.applicationId=<CG_INP_PROCESS>
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.inpProcess1-in-0.consumer.applicationId=<CG_INP1_PROCESS>
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.processing.guarentee=exactly_once
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.isolation.level=read_committed
```

Also please do let me know if exactly once can behave weirdly because as per our use case

```
1st use case

Sending to topic -> doing some processing -> send to rabbit mq -> get the response -> send it back to the same topic 

That is using only 1 topic for reading and writing
```

```
2nd use case

Send to topic -> some processing-> send to other topic -> some processing-> rabbit mq -> send back to first topic 

Here also at end will come back to 1st topic
```

So in both scenarios there is a cycle at some point. Please could someone advise on this.

Comment: What version is your broker? Brokers older than 2.0 expired consumer offsets after 24 hours elapse without consuming a message (even if the consumer was still connected). 2.0 changed this to 7 days. 2.1 changed it to 7 days since the last consumer left a group.

Comment: I am using Kafka version 2.5.1

Comment: Then I have no explanation as to why the committed offset is lost; sorry.

Comment: Could you please once check if I have missed something in the properties or if they are wrong? And also if having a cycle may affect exactly once semantics? And any turnaround I can do for it

Comment: It looks ok to me; I don't see how writing back to the same topic would affect anything, the new write goes to a different offset (obviously if you write back the exact same data, it will be delivered from the new offset). Perhaps your broker has its [offsets.retention.minutes](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_offsets.retention.minutes) reduced from the default 7 days?

Comment: Got it thank you! I will check upon the property offsets.retention.minutes value. No won't be writing same data.